# How to wrap std::uint32_t function(const std::initializer_list<std::uint32_t>& Arglist in pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am trying to wrap an external C++ library for use in python3, and got completely stuck with this function:

std::uint32_t sendCommand( const std::initializer_liststd::uint32_t& tArgList )
template<typename... Args> void sendCommand( const Args&... args )

is it at all possible to wrap this in pybind11 ??

I am compiling with
g++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++17 -fPIC $(python3 -m pybind11 --includes)

/usr/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:1158:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
wrapper.cpp:43:39: note:   mismatched types ‘pybind11::detail::initimpl::pickle_factory<Args ...>’ and ‘const char [8]’
43 |       .def("sendCommand",&Class1::sendCommand)